# Formato de fechas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una variable de tipo **SMALLDATETIME**

```
DECLARE @Fecha smallDateTime = '20190123 11:06:50 PM';
```

y quisiera convertirla en varchar pero que me devuelva algo asi **2019/01/23 11:06:50 PM**

y yo tengo esto:

```
select  @Fecha = CONVERT(smalldatetime, @Fecha, 109)
select  @Fecha
```

pero me devuelve esto:

```
2019-01-23 23:07:00
```

¿me pueden ayudar con esto por favor?

Comment: select convert(varchar, @Fecha 109) deberia de funcionar

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto,

```
declare @fecha datetime = getdate()
select Replace(convert(varchar(10),@fecha, 121) + right(convert(varchar(32),@fecha,100),8), '-', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

podes usar la función DATE_CONVERT

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@Fecha, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i %p')
```

Comment: me marca error dice que DATE_FORMAT no e suna funcion.

Comment: mi error, eso es para mysql

Answer (score 0):

puede usar la función convert a datatime

ejemplo:

si lo requiere como varchar

```
select convert(varchar(10),convert(date,@Fecha), 111) +' '+ right(convert(varchar(32),@Fecha,100),12)
```

Comment: eso me devolvería la fecha actual.

Comment: solo hay que sustituirlo por el valor de tu fecha

Comment: eso es para cambiar de varchar a date y solo te devolvería la fecha sin horas

Comment: Cambia la longitud del RIGHT() de 12 a 7, actualmente está regresando el año

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:MM:ss tt') as date
```

resultado: 2019/05/16 05:05:47 PM

*** a partir de SQL Server 2012

Comment: Nota importante: FORMAT puede ser hasta 40 veces más lento que CONVERT.